# FLutter Android Plugin, onDestroy function is not attached to the plugin class

Tags: java, android, flutter, flutter-plugin

i am creating a plugin with the `onAttachedToEngine` function that i use to assign context and mediaPlayer session to variables, exactly like the docs say so nothing special is being done. The problem is that when my plugin throws an error and it's time for the `onDestroy` function to be called, the onDestroy function doesn't seem to see the variables i set during the usage of the current object.

so if i set a variable X to "hello" in the `onAttachedToEngine`, `onDestroy` will keep seeing it as null and creates nullPointer exceptions which crashes my plugin and app.

here is a sample code i am using :

```
public class flutterPlugin extends MediaBrowserService implements FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {
  private String randomString = "lowercase";

 private void initInstance(BinaryMessenger binaryMessenger, Context context) {
    this.channel = new MethodChannel(binaryMessenger, ID);
    this.channel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
    am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mContext=context;
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    setupBroadcastReceiver();
    startSession(mContext);
    this.randomStirng = "UPPERCASE";

  }


  @Override
  public void onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
    this.initInstance(binding.getBinaryMessenger(), binding.getApplicationContext());
  }


  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {

  this.randomStirng // here the random string i initialized is equal to "lowercase"
  // and the same goes for all the variables initialized in initInstance, they are alll treated an null
  (...)
  }

(...)
}
```

what could the issue be ? is onDestroy being called from a child process ? when getting the parent of `super` it returns the same class name as the plugin

Comment: Hih Kaki, did you find any way to fix this up ? I'm in the same situation as you are...

Comment: @evaisse i stopped using onDestroy function, and i put eerything in the activity and attachment methods and it worked correctly

Comment: Hi @kaki, there is indeed an issue that seems to be fixed in v3.7.10 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/124201#issuecomment-1498495926 anyway I’m curious how do you call the plugin instance from the activity class ?